# Crop and center arbitrarily-sized image within a div

Tags: javascript, css, image, html

I have a `div` within which I would like to put any **arbitrarily**-sized image, preferably using an `img` tag rather than the CSS `background-image` style. I've looked at many other similar questions and none have answered my question.

The way I would like the image to display is this:

1. If the image is portrait (height is greater than width), the image will have a width of 100% within the `div` and be vertically centered. The extra height will be outside of the div, but **not visible** (as in, the image would appear 'cropped'.)
2. If it is landscape, the properties in #1 would apply, but horizontally instead of vertically.

I do **not** want to stretch the image. I **do** want to fill the entire space within the div.

An example of this would be the image boxes that appear on [imgur.com](http://imgur.com/).

Comment: I can't figure out how to display the image without stretching it to fit the div or displaying at 100% size, which causes only the top lefthand corner of the image to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try centering it with javascript. Just set the `position: absolute`, `left:50%`, `top:50%` and `margin-left:-width/2`, `margin-top:-height/2`

Comment: `position: absolute`? Do you mean `position: relative`?

Comment: @CSStudent Try one or another and see. Relative takes up space, absolute doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised this question doesn't have an easy to find answer anywhere online, but I came up with a (mostly) pure CSS solution that might help someone. The idea is that there are two possible sizes for the image:

1. Width is 100% of the parent, height is determined by aspect ratio
2. Height is 100% of the parent, width is determined by aspect ratio

Of these two options, the one that is preferred is simply the bigger one, since the smaller one will leave gaps around the edges. Therefore, we can use a div in between container and image to "calculate" the larger size. Here's my code:

```js
const image = document.getElementById("image");
const sizer = document.getElementById("sizer");

image.onload = () => {
  const aspectRatio = image.width / image.height;
  sizer.style = `aspect-ratio: ${aspectRatio}`;
};
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  
  resize: both;
}

#sizer {
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:0px;
  transform: translate(-50%,0);
}

#image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:50%;
  transform: translate(0,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="sizer">
    <img id="image" src="https://www.industrialempathy.com/img/remote/ZiClJf-1920w.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try dragging around the corner of the image to check how it works.

The only JS required is to fix the aspect ratio of the sizer, and it's quite lightweight (only required when the image src is loaded). I believe this will also work across almost all browsers and versions, since the CSS is very basic.

Hope this helps someone!